# How can i do functions that come after each other after every period

Tags: javascript, function

I was always curious about how functions are run after each other after a period. e.g

```
let result = function1().function2(param).function3()
```

How can I do this?

Comment: function1 simply has to return something that has function2 on its prototype

Comment: @chrispbacon Thanks, but maybe an example will make it more understandable, Did not understand what you meant by prototype

Comment: Usually in such circumstances `function1` etc need to be methods on the same object - in that case it's as simple as having each method `return this` after doing whatever it does.

Comment: @chrispbacon Thank for the term "method chaining"

Comment: You're welcome. This one seems to be a good read https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/understanding-method-chaining-in-javascript-647a9004bd4f; much better than the answer you received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of ways to do it, depends on your needs.
If you are just looking for a chain of functions this is a simple example:

```
function function1() { // function 1
    return params => { // function 2
        return () => { // function 3
            return result;
        }
    }
}
// usage
const result = function1()(params)()
```

Or

```
function function1() {
    this.function2 = function2;
    return this;
}

function function2(params) {
    this.function3 = function3;
    return this;
}

function function3() {
    return 'xxx';
}
// usage
const result = function1().function2(params).function3();
```

Other option is to use chain of Promises for async methods.